# Does the tongues of fire incident make it clear, that all such events have now ceased?

Tags: cessationism, speaking-in-tongues, pentecost

This question, addressed to Trinitarian Protestants, regards the *nature* of the incident related by Luke, Acts 2:3, when a manifestation of fiery tongues was seen in association with the eleven, after the ascension of Jesus Christ.

It is notable that the only manifestation of the Holy Spirit, *himself*, is when, in a direct involvement between Father and Son, he is seen bodily descending, Luke 3:22, in a dove-like form, upon the newly baptised Jesus. I suggest that the manifestation of tongues is not that of the Person, himself, but rather of *what is being gifted*, as a *result* of the Person’s indwelling.

Most Protestant Trinitarian commentators of whom I am aware have viewed the manifestation of the Angel of the Lord, or of other angelic presences (such as the three coming to Abraham, the one with whom Jacob wrestled, the angel seen going up in a flame by Manoah and his wife, and the presence in the fiery furnace) as *temporary manifestations* of He who would, later, be fully incarnate.

None, that I know of, attribute any such manifestations as being of the Person of the Holy Spirit, making the visibility of the descent, as a dove, a *unique event*. And I have never heard or read any suggestion that such would ever be expected to happen again to any other person.

The Head has been anointed and the body shall receive the anointing via the Head and within that body.

Then the fact of tongues only ever being seen to visibly descend upon the eleven, and those directly associated with them and nobody else, might therefore suggest that this event is, also, unique, the only other comparable occurrence being, Acts 19:2, in the case of twelve who, since they had never even heard of the Holy Spirit, could not have been aware of either of the above events and therefore were granted an experience similar to, though differing from, that which was unique.

Does the *unique character* of these events not point to a non-repetition of them and point to a considered and balanced attitude that such things have, indeed, ceased ?

I am interested in hearing argument, to the contrary, from a Protestant and Trinitarian standpoint.

---

As stated below in comment : the unique character of the tongues incident (similar to the uniqueness of the descent) suggests to me a non-repetition and I am looking for reasoned arguments to the contrary.

Comment: To be honest, I'm finding this question a little hard to work out exactly what you're asking about (are you asking about strictly visible manifestations of the Spirit?), but seeing as Protestantism includes both Pentecostals and cessationists, I wouldn't expect any kind of consensus on such matters.

Comment: @curiousdannii I will ponder an edit, but I thought it was clear that the _unique character_ of the tongues incident (similar to the uniqueness of the descent) suggests to me a non-repetition and I am looking for reasoned arguments to the contrary.

Answer (score 3):

You provided three main examples - Luke 3:22, Acts, 2:3, and finally Acts 19:2. We have then 3 for-sure examples of the Holy Spirit working as an individual Person of the Trinity.

There is one verse in the Bible that indicates cessation of speaking in tongues.

1 Corinthians 13:8, ESV: "Love never ends. As for prophecies, they will pass away; as for tongues, they will cease; as for knowledge, it will pass away."

Cessationists interpret this to mean that tongues have stopped. Yet, it says also that *knowledge will pass away*. We still have knowledge, and there is nothing to indicate them ending at separate times (Note: tongues could mean languages here). Furthermore, there is context surrounding this, vs9-10: "For we know in part and we prophesy in part, but when the perfect comes, the partial will pass away."

Thus, it indicates itself that the will *not* cease until the Second Coming. In my final point concerning this verse, some will claim that the Greek indicates that they will cease before "the perfect comes". It is not so, as we can see by looking at other context of the verb.

However, the Question asks if the "unique character" implies a cessation of gifts.

If we were flip a coin, and it landed on heads 100 times in a row, it does not mean that it can't land on tails - while I don't want to compare God to chance, just because something doesn't happen doesn't mean it can't - the intertestamental period attests to this.

I will not argue the "unique character" of the Holy Spirit coming down as fire and resting on the Twelve all at once - no Protestant can claim that this has happened since with any grounding.

Paul tells us, after apparently speaking in tongues has ceased, he says in 1 Corinthians 12:8-11:

"For to one is given through the Spirit the utterance of wisdom, and to another the utterance of knowledge according to the same Spirit, to another faith by the same Spirit, to another gifts of healing by the one Spirit, to another the working of miracles, to another prophecy, to another the ability to distinguish between spirits, to another various kinds of tongues, to another the interpretation of tongues. All these are empowered by one and the same Spirit, who apportions to each one individually as he wills."

There is nothing to indicate anything has changed - while perhaps rarer, they surely have not stopped.

It would be foolish to think that miracles of the Father have ceased - He is personal and works in our lives. It is the same with the Spirit as well as Jesus, who worked around 30 miracles on earth, more now  that He is in Heaven, surely we don't except the Spirit?

[What is speaking in tongues?](https://www.gotquestions.org/gift-of-tongues.html)

Comment: So I would ask why there is no instruction to either Timothy or Titus (who, after Paul's decease, were to ensure that the churches were properly governed and administrated) regarding this (suggested as a very prominent feature of fellowship and worship) aspect of the church ? And the text you cite , 1 Corinthians 12:8-11 could refer to _translation_ of languages. But from what I have seen and heard, interpretation (of what is called 'tongues') is rarely, if ever, attempted in modern times

Comment: I think that is the interpretation of tongues, which does likely refer to the interpretation - however, there are two gifts concerning tongues, or languages. I think the one listed first does indeed support my point, but I agree that one is concerning translation of the Word.